# addArrangedSubview without animations

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview, tzstackview

I add views to a `TZStackView` (which should be basically the same as a `UIStackView`, but with a fallback for older versions) like this:

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(subview)
```

the `stackView` and the `subview` are of dynamic size (auto-layout) and resize themselves. However, this happens with an animation (I think due to `addArrangedSubview`, it does not happen if I add it as subview and set constraints). Is there a way to deactivate the animations?

Comment: Have you tried a UIView performWithoutAnimation: block?

Comment: I don't want an animation, I want to disable the animation that is happening

Comment: I know... that's why I suggested you try perform*Without*Animation

Comment: Sorry, I read `performWithAnimation`, I didn't even know `performWithoutAnimation` existed, but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: It actually DOES work. Please write it as an answer so I can accept it ;) and thanks a lot, I have been searching for something that works the whole day :)

Comment: No problem.  I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: @simpleBob how did it work for you? I just add stackView.addArrangedSubview(subview) in the performWithoutAnimation: block, but it still animates.

Comment: @yeesterbunny I solved it specifically for my case, but putting `layoutIfNeeded` in the `UIView.performWithoutAnimation` block instead should work

Comment: @simpleBob That was eventually what I did, and it worked! I wouldn't had solved it without seeing your post. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel did you put `stackView.layoutIfNeeded()` or your stack view's superview `layoutIfNeeded()` in the block? One of my arranged subviews is still animating.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Disabling animations while adding arranged views to a UIStackView does not work properly in iOS 9.

The solution is to perform the addition separately from the layout:

```
// Add all views first.

for view in views {
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
}

// Now force the layout in one hit, sans animation.

UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    stackView.setNeedsLayout()
    stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Tested on iOS 9.3, Xcode 8.3.2. 
Not tested on iOS 10 or 11 yet.

Comment: from @mrfonda: `Tested on iOS11, Xcode 9.0 (9A235)`

Comment: After upgrading to iOS11 my app had begun animating. This code helped me preventing the unwanted animation. Xcode 9.0.1 (9A1004)

Comment: stackView.addArrangedSubview(button01)
      stackView.insertArrangedSubview(button02, at: 0)
             
            UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }

worked for me tested in iOS 11 and 12

Comment: **for 2023** ... the situation has yet again changed and I find that in some cases the performWithoutAnimation "does work" - that is to say, wrap ALL the insertions inside one performWithoutAnimation.

Answer (score 12):

UIView performWithoutAnimation: will execute its block argument without animation:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(subview)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Xcode 8.3.2, iOS 9.3. Regardless of where you add the 'performWithoutAnimation' call, there is still some animation happening. It just changes the nature of the animation. I regard this as a bug and a mis-featured API. See new Answer for a solution in iOS 9.

Comment: @Womble , if you're still there *"the situation has yet again changed and I find that in some cases the performWithoutAnimation "does work" - that is to say, wrap ALL the insertions inside one performWithoutAnimation"*  Also, I sent a bounty for your great answer TY :)